# Add strings to a set without quotes (Python)

Tags: python, string, set, quote

So I have two classes Student and UniClass. I want to have the **str** method of UniClass give out the string of a set which contains multiple strings given by the **str** method of Student.
The code I have written for this in order to work is:

```
def __str__(self):
        """Gives back a String in the form 'name [imt_name] in Semester semester'"""
        return '{} [{}] in Semester {}'.format(self.name, self.imt_name, self.semester)
```

For the student Class and

```
def __str__(self):
        """without a student object, "set()" is returned, with one or multiple student objects, a string containing of the strings from the student class is returned"""
        if self._students == set():
            return "set()"
        else:
            rückgabe = set()
            for student in self._students:
                rückgabe.add(str(student))
            return str(rückgabe)
```

in order to get back the string if I call an object of UniClass.

So for example, if I have a student object with `name = "David"`, `imt_name = "D3123"` and `semester = 3`, the `__str__` method of student should give back a string `"David [D3123] in Semester 3"` and the UniClass should give back the string `"{David [D3123] in Semester 3}"`. If there were multiple student objects in one UniClass object they should be given back in this form seperated by commas.

While everything works fine, the only problem I have is that the string given back by the UniClass Class is in the Form `{'David[D3123] in Semester 2', 'Jonas [J312344] in Semester 3'}`, which is not fine since the string will be tested and **has** to have the form of the upper paragraph without the quotes.

Is there a way to have the strings represented in the set without quotes without using the strip method (because I already tried that, and the string didn't change at all)?

Comment: Would `return ', '.join(rückgabe)` work?  Then you just need the extra `{}` in your format string?

Comment: Works, thank you very much!

Comment: However I dont think that the task was ment to be solved this way. I'll go with it and ask my tutor next week :)

Comment: I mean ... ostensibly.  But also - your other options are to futz with the `__repr__` or `__str__` methods of your set, and I doubt that's a good approach.